# QGC Android Build Crashes Immediately

Tags: android, qt, qgroundcontrol

I am able to successfully build QGC for android using version "Stable_V4.3". I am trying to run it on my device but it always crashes with this error in the Application Output:

```
D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E AndroidRuntime: Process: org.mavlink.qgroundcontrol2, PID: 32756
E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.mavlink.qgroundcontrol2/org.mavlink.qgroundcontrol2.QGCActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.mavlink.qgroundcontrol2.QGCActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.mavlink.qgroundcontrol2-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.mavlink.qgroundcontrol2-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/org.mavlink.qgroundcontrol2-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2568)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
E AndroidRuntime:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E AndroidRuntime:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
E AndroidRuntime:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.mavlink.qgroundcontrol2.QGCActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.mavlink.qgroundcontrol2-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.mavlink.qgroundcontrol2-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/org.mavlink.qgroundcontrol2-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
E AndroidRuntime:   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
E AndroidRuntime:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
E AndroidRuntime:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2558)
E AndroidRuntime:   ... 9 more
16:30:37: 

"org.mavlink.qgroundcontrol2" died.
```

I am using Windows 11 with Qt version 5.15.2 and Qt Creator 11.0.3.

SDK Build tools default to 34 but I have tried to run it with 25 too (same error)
Device APK level : 25
NDK : 21
CompileSDK Version defaults to 31, tried it with 25. Still fails.

Another thing is that the same build runs successfully on Android Emulator, arm-architectured (APK 25).

The error occurs on both debug and release version.